# Wine can’t run program - how to fix

Tags: ubuntu, virtualbox, wine

Linux Version: Ubuntu Virtual Box VM

I’m trying to use Wine but when I run programs in it I get a wall of errors. I’m not sure how to fix them.

```
00f:err:service:process_send_command receiving command result timed out
0009:err:dmloader:IDirectMusicLoaderImpl_SetObject : could not attach stream to file L"C:\windows\system32\drivers\gm.dls", make sure it exists
0009:err:winediag:MIDIMAP_drvOpen No software synthesizer midi port found, Midi sound output probably won't work.
0009:err:ole:CoGetClassObject class {87fc0268-9a55-4360-95aa-004a1d9de26c} not registered
0009:err:ole:CoGetClassObject no class object {87fc0268-9a55-4360-95aa-004a1d9de26c} could be created for context 0x1
0009:err:ole:CoGetClassObject class {efe6629c-81f7-4281-bd91-c9d604a95af6} not registered
0009:err:ole:CoGetClassObject no class object {efe6629c-81f7-4281-bd91-c9d604a95af6} could be created for context 0x1
0009:err:ole:CoGetClassObject class {efca3d92-dfd8-4672-a603-7420894bad98} not registered
0009:err:ole:CoGetClassObject no class object {efca3d92-dfd8-4672-a603-7420894bad98} could be created for context 0x1
0009:err:ole:CoGetClassObject class {efe6629c-81f7-4281-bd91-c9d604a95af6} not registered
0009:err:ole:CoGetClassObject no class object {efe6629c-81f7-4281-bd91-c9d604a95af6} could be created for context 0x1
0009:err:ole:CoGetClassObject class {efca3d92-dfd8-4672-a603-7420894bad98} not registered
0009:err:ole:CoGetClassObject no class object {efca3d92-dfd8-4672-a603-7420894bad98} could be created for context 0x1
0009:err:ole:CoGetClassObject class {efe6629c-81f7-4281-bd91-c9d604a95af6} not registered
0009:err:ole:CoGetClassObject no class object {efe6629c-81f7-4281-bd91-c9d604a95af6} could be created for context 0x1
```

Answer (score 2):

Find the app at https://appdb.winehq.org - if there's none, try running it under Wine 6.11 (this is your distro dependent), if the app still doesn't run, file a bug report at https://bugs.winehq.org

Maybe you're looking at https://bugs.winehq.org/show_bug.cgi?id=35478

```
winetricks dsdmo
```

Could fix it.

Comment: Unfortunately winetricks did not work. Any other ideas?

Comment: @user64742 I've given you the exact instructions how to deal with the situation.